# Ajax call not ended in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using jsf with prime faces, i have came across one situation. I called bean's method using prime faces command button with Ajax true action. The call takes long time to respond after the response on complete is not fired, i have called a java script to stop the loader for that call.But on complete is not fired.

I have ensured that called  method ends in bean, but on complete event not fired.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Connection timeout is not handled by PrimeFaces on ajax requests. But you should check in first line, why you are getting that timeouts.

Comment: Because i am calling externel interface. It will take more time to respond.

Comment: So you have a big design flaw. You should notice client asynchronously about the changes. AJAX push and poll are the keywords.